# is it possible to get the physical path of the given filename in .net?

Tags: .net

I want to get the physical path of given file name. For

EX: i have my project in drive E:\ and need to search the physical path of "x.txt" file which is resides in C drive.

Comment: yes/no question, the answer is Possible.

Comment: Duplicate of [c# Find a file within all possible folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225294/c-sharp-find-a-file-within-all-possible-folders). What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```cs
var matchingFilePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\")
                          .Where(filePath => filePath.EndsWith("x.txt"));
```

If you need to work with the file contents, you can start with using `FileInfo`:

```cs
var fileInfo = new FileInfo("path\to\file.ext");
var fullPath = fileInfo.FullName;
```

Putting it together:

```cs
var matchingFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\")
                      .Where(filePath => filePath.EndsWith("x.txt"))
                      .Select(filePath => new FileInfo(filePath).FullName);
```