# Get file path if file is in another folder

Tags: c#, file

I have a text file inside a drive. Probably inside a folder in the drive. I know the filename and drive name. I searches the file occurance through

`var file = Directory.GetFiles(ftpPath,fileName,SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

That is ok. But if the file is in a folder under the drive how could I get the ne path in `ftpPath` variable?

I could not find any valid solution for this.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225294/c-sharp-find-a-file-within-all-possible-folders). Seems like they are doing the same thing.

Comment: I have the Drive. I just need the full path if its under a folder. They are talking about filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
ftpPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(file[0]);
```

Now the path in which `filename` was found in is stored in `ftpPath`.
Of course you should add some checks before accessing file to ensure it was actually found...

Answer (score 0):

To parse the path of a path + filename string use:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ftpPath);
```

ftpPath = `@"C:\Path\To\The\File\Filename.dll";`
    will output `@"C:\Path\To\The\File"`