# (How to) Use Windows file explorer to find an application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to open programmaticaly an application.

First i used `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Program1.exe")` works fine, but the application always needs to  be on the same path (not always true because different computer)

And a simple way to find it  (with mouse & click, not programmaticaly though) is to use the windows file explorer, i enter the title of my application and i find it instantly.

I would like to code that.

I thought i could use the keyboard shortcut "Home + F" and simulate the word with `SendKeys.Send("blabla"`) but the "Home key" doesn't seem to exist with c# (at least not here https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms127847(v=vs.110).aspx)

It's a little program for children i can't expect them to find manually the path (so forget the `OpenFileDialog`..)

Maybe thats a very bad idea and there are another solution to find a program without knowing his path, i don't know have you got better idea?!

Comment: Instead of automating Windows File Explorer, just use the built-in C# methods to find the file: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1225294/87698

Comment: Works almost fine but make my computer freeze... like a lot.

Comment: You could use Heinzi's solution. WITH application.config to write the path in there. So the first time you show a loading dialog. and after that you just read from the application.config file

Comment: Is it just "Program Files" with or without the "(x86)" (depending on 32 or 64 bit os + application), or could that "Program1.exe" have been installed anywhere?

Comment: that's the issue, it can be anywhere... it's installed by usb key ...

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to solve the problem the wrong way.  What you're trying to "program" is the setting oft the *working directory* when the program is run using Explorer.  The *right* way to do that is to use `Process.Start` by passing it all of the necessary info to start the process:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Program1.exe");
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\";

Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: i can't use that it could be installed anywhere!

Comment: OK I misunderstood - you want to programatically _search_ for the app?